# How i can send notification to specific user in android?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

There is two user A and B. User A requested to ring Alarm of user B.How I can ring user B device on request of user A. As there is no any connection between devices. Or how I can send notification alarm to user B stating that User A requested to ring your device.

Is there any way to implement it.